# При нажатии на кнопку во фрагменте ничего не происходит

Tags: java, android

Не так давно, буквально пару дней назад, начал изучать фрагменты, возникла следующая проблема: при нажатии на кнопку во фрагменте не срабатывает код, точнее не происходит вообще ничего. Не могу найти в чем проблема.

```
    EditText koefA;
    EditText koefB;
    EditText koefC;
    TextView result;
    Button resultButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        koefA = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.koefA);
        koefB = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.koefB);
        koefC =  (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.koefC);
        result = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Result);
        resultButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.getResult);
        resultButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;


    }

    private void QuadDiffer()
    {
        try {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(koefA.getText().toString());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(koefB.getText().toString());
            int c = Integer.parseInt(koefC.getText().toString());
            int diskrim = b * b - 4 * a * c;
            if (diskrim < 0) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Дискриминант < 0. Корни отсутствуют", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            } else {
                double x1 = (double) (-b + Math.sqrt(diskrim) / 2 * a);
                double x2 = (double) (-b - Math.sqrt(diskrim) / 2 * a);
                result.setText("x1 and x2 = " + x1 + " , " + x2);
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Вы не ввели коефициент. Повторите еще раз", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.getResult:
                QuadDiffer();
                break;
        }
     }
}
```

Вот код MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "SECTION 1";
                case 1:
                    return "SECTION 2";
                case 2:
                    return "SECTION 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: implements OnClickListener имеется во фрагменте?

Comment: Артем да, конечно